# Specifying the linear predictor, survival function and PDF of a log-normal survival distribution

Tags: sas, survival, lognormal-distribution

Continuing on my exploration of the log-normal distribution, I'm working on reimplementing some code originally written for a Weibull/Exponential model for a log-normal model. Among the things it does is use SAS's PROX NLMIXED to hard-calculate some likelihoods. While this is technically SAS code, I think it's pretty readable in a code-agnostic fashion.

For example, the Weibull Version:

```
*Linear Predictor of Event A
lam=exp(-(f0*alpha+f1*alpha*X));

*Density of Event A;
ff1=alpha*lam*t1**(alpha-1)*exp(-lam*t1**alpha);
ff2=alpha*lam*t2**(alpha-1)*exp(-lam*t2**alpha);

*Survival function of Event A;
sf1=exp(-lam*t1**alpha);
sf2=exp(-lam*t2**alpha);
```

The two survival functions are just at two different points in time for interval censoring.

I've implemented, I believe, the appropriate survival and density functions for a Log-Normal as follows:

```
*Density of EventA;
ff1 = exp(-0.5*((log(t1)-mu)/sigma)**2)/((t1*(2*CONSTANT('PI'))**0.5)*sigma);
ff2 = exp(-0.5*((log(t2)-mu)/sigma)**2)/((t2*(2*CONSTANT('PI'))**0.5)*sigma);

*Survival function of EventA;
sf1= 1 - CDF('Normal',((log(t1)-mu)/sigma));
sf2= 1 - CDF('Normal',((log(t2)-mu)/sigma));
```

I guess the first part of the question is does that appear correct? My second question is where I'm getting caught up, actually defining the linear predictor for the log normal. I think it should be something along the form of:

`mu = exp(f0+f1*X)` ala the Weibull above and with sigma estimated outside the linear predictor, but I'm not positive. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Edit: The goal PDF once the syntax errors are fixed is:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Epi. The code looks pretty close, except I think `ff1` and `ff2` have misplaced parentheses (syntax error) and `sf2` should use `t2`, probably. Other than that, think of the lognormal just like it sounds: The log of the random variable is normal. So, if you wanted to do OLS, e.g., $\log Y$ would be your response variable. That should tell you how the predictors should enter in your scenario. :)

Comment: Should it be something like: `ff1 = exp(-0.5*((log(t1)-mu)/sigma)**2)/(t1*sigma*(2*CONSTANT('PI'))**0.5)`?

Comment: @cardinal I edited the code to, I believe, fix the problem. I'll post the actual function in an edit because it may be easier to keep track of than code.

Comment: Ok. I'm much more comfortable with `R`, but I was just trying to match parentheses in a natural way to get them to come in the order I expected. Note that right after the first `**2`, that close parentheses has no matching open one. Also, I'm guessing based on standard rules of evaluation that the `*sigma` at the end will be in the numerator and not the denominator (where it should be). I realize my previous comments regarding this were likely too terse to be very useful. I'll await your further edits before commenting further. :-)

Comment: @cardinal Don't underestimate their utility - the first one caused me to rethink what I had as the linear predictor. I *believe* I've fixed the functions now - there's a proper close parentheses, and the denominator is all wrapped up together.

Comment: @cardinal With these edits it now runs, and at least generates a semi-sane answer. Whether it's *correct* is another question.

Comment: @EpiGard: I have not read your code... but simulations should be quite easy to set up and should at least give you some confidence on whether you did it well... Also, it might be possible to compare with existing implementations in SAS (proc lifereg) or in R (survreg()).

Comment: @ocram That's the next step :)

Comment: Update: Simulations seem to be failing, but right now I'm more suspicious of my simulations than I am of this code.