# PROC NLMIXED and PROC LIFEREG not arriving at the same answer for Log-normal survival function

Tags: sas, survival

[Related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34414/specifying-the-linear-predictor-survival-function-and-pdf-of-a-log-normal-survi)

I have a project where, despite being able to implement some parametric models in LIFEREG, it is somewhat more convenient to do it in NLMIXED. Verifying that this technique works, I tried implementing a pretty bog standard Weibull AFT as follows:

```
data work.data;
    call streaminit(123);
    do i = 1 to 1000;
        x = rand('BERN', 0.10); *10% exposed;
        t1 = rand('Weibull', 1, 20*(exp(-0.500*x)));
        t2 = t1;
        weight = 1;
        output;
    end;
run;

PROC NLMIXED data=work.data fd;
    parms alpha=1 f0=-1 f1=0;
    bounds alpha>0;
    *Rate of x;
    lam=exp(-(f0*alpha+f1*alpha*x));    

    *Density of x;
    ff1=alpha*lam*t1**(alpha-1)*exp(-lam*t1**alpha);

    *log Likelihood;
    logl=log(ff1);

    *Weighted log Likelihood;
    wlogl=logl*weight;
    model t1~general(wlogl);
    ods exclude iterhistory parameters;
run; quit; run;

proc lifereg data=work.data;    
    model (t1, t2) = x / D=WEIBULL; 
    weight weight; run;
```

This works swimmingly. Both LIFEREG and NLMIXED produce the same estimates, and all is right in the world. Testing it for a Log-Normal AFT model however using the following modifications doesn't work so well:

```
PROC NLMIXED data=work.data fd;
    parms sigma=1 g0=-1 g1=0;
    bounds sigma>0;

    *Rate of X;
    mu=exp(g0+g1*x);

    *Density of X;
    fg1 = exp(-0.5*((log(t1)-mu)/sigma)**2)/((t1*(2*CONSTANT('PI'))**0.5)*sigma);

    *log Likelihood;
    logl=log(fg1);

    *Weighted log Likelihood;
    wlogl=logl*weight;
    estimate "RT NDD" exp(g1);
    model x~general(wlogl);
    ods exclude iterhistory parameters;
run;

proc lifereg data=work.data;
    model (t1, t2) = x / D=Lnormal; 
    weight weight;run;
```

Here, while both models estimate the scale as the same number (1.2676), the estimates for the intercept (g0) and x (g1) are wildly off. In NLMIXED they are 0.8747 and -0.1419 respectively, while in LIFEREG they are 2.3981 and -0.3172.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I don't quite understand how this works.  Lifereg is a form of regression model that is structured to fit survival curves which have special constraints F(t)=1 at t=0 F(t) goes to zero and at least in the limit as t approaches infinity F(t) approaches 0 and F is monotonic nonincreasing.  Nlmixed fits a nonlinear model with mixed effects and no particular constraints on the response variable.  How do you force the constraints and the form of the model in nlmixed to match the form of lifereg and guarantee that you are using the same estimation method?

Comment: Lifereg is designed for survival curve modeling nlmixed is not.  So why use nlmixed?

Comment: @MichaelChernick One can used NLMIXED pretty flexibly - here, essentially what I've done is forced the likelihood function NLMIXED is fitting to be the same (theoretically) that LIFEREG is using. NLMIXED can actually be considered more of a flexible likelihood estimation framework - it works for mixed models, but you can use it for other things. There's things NLMIXED does that LIFEREG does not. This example happens not to use them, but that's because it's a test case.

Comment: I know SAS pretty well but I do not know all the options of procedures like NLMIXED.  So I will concede that it may be possible to force NLMIXED to fit a survival function.  Of course NLMIXED does things that LIFEREG doesn't do. LIFEREG is exclusively designed to fit survival functions.  Nevertheless it is not easy to fit a square peg in a round whole.  There are many options that you have to select properly to make the procedures perform the exact same function.  You really better understand these option and know what they do to the model. There are various estimation options. (cont)

Comment: @MichaelChernick Agreed. However as we've been talking, managed to do some debugging and find the problem. If you'd like, I'll send you on the details of *why* I'm using NLMIXED once it's a little more polished.

Comment: The distributions (Weibull models can have different parameterization).  Maybe you did everything perfectly right and the models are identical with alternative parameterizations.  But there are so many places where you could slip up and cause the model not to match.

Comment: Note that $\exp(0.8747) \approx 2.398156$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:

The rate of x is incorrectly specified as `mu=exp(g0+g1*x)`. Once this is corrected to `mu = (g0+g1*x)` LIFEREG and NLMIXED arrive at the same answer.

Comment: Excellent. I am glad you found the misspecification. I suppose if it works as it apparently does and you can do it right maybe there is a reason that justifies all this laborious work!  Look forward to hearing about it.